# how to have different labelling option for different set of nodes in networkx visualisation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I have a graph that consists of three sets of nodes 1. servers 2. stations 3. users
I want to draw them with networks built-in visualization. In the drawing, I want to have the labels for users and stations but not for servers. However, this doesn't work. when I try this:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(network,
                    with_labels=False,
                    nodelist=self.servers_idx,
                    node_size=50, node_shape='s',
                    pos=servers_pos,
                    node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(network, with_labels=True,
                    nodelist=self.stations_idx,
                    node_size=50, node_shape='^',
                    pos=stations_pos,
                    node_color='g')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(network, with_labels=True,
                    nodelist=self.users_idx,
                    node_size=10, node_shape='o',
                    pos=users_pos,
                    node_color='b')
```

I get the following figure:

[image]

which as you see shows none of the labels, but I have set the `with_labels` variable value to `True` for stations and users and the expectation is that it will show them. The strange thing is that when I set all the `with_labels` to `True` it will show all the labels. But if I only set one of them to `False` it will not show the other two (like that I have set all of them False). Does anyone have any idea what is happening here?

Comment: This looks very much like a bug, I would raise an issue on their github, including some example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul Brodersen said, it looks like a networkx bug. But you can go around it by using [`nx.draw_networkx_labels`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels) function for users and stations, but not for servers:

```
import networkx as nx

network = nx.Graph()
network.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

# Manually create positions and indices
servers_pos = {1: (-1, 1), 2: (1, 1)}
stations_pos = {3: (0, -1), 4: (1, 0)}
users_pos = {5: (0, 0)}
servers_idx = [1, 2]
stations_idx = [3, 4]
users_idx = [5]

# Draw nodes (exactly your code, but without `with_labels` attribute)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(network, nodelist=[1, 2], node_size=50, node_shape='s', pos=servers_pos, node_color='r')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(network, nodelist=[3, 4], node_size=50, node_shape='^', pos=stations_pos, node_color='g')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(network, nodelist=[5], node_size=10, node_shape='o', pos=users_pos, node_color='b')

# Manually create labels for users and stations
stations_labels = {3: 'WAKA-3', 4: 'WAKA-4'}
users_labels = {5: 'John Doe'}
nx.draw_networkx_labels(
    network,
    pos=stations_pos,
    labels=stations_labels
)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(
    network,
    pos=users_pos,
    labels=users_labels
)
```

Here is the result:

[image]